# When pressing field calculator icon Ubuntu log out!

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, ubuntu

I'm having a weird issue, as said in the title when I press the field calculator button the operative system log out. 
Anyone as experienced this issue?

I'm running qgis 2.18 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: There's one field calculator button in the attribute table, and another button in the main QGIS window. Does your problem occur with each of the buttons?